# Row-wise cumulative product on large data.table benchmarking

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table, benchmarking

Suppose I have a large data.table with about 1000 columns and 100,000 rows like this:

```
dt <- data.table(col1 = runif(10^4))
for (i in 2:10^3) set(dt, j = paste('col', as.character(i), sep = ''), value = dt[[i-1]] * 0.95^(i-1))
```

Think of these as representing 'daily mortality rates'. I want to calculate monthly survival rates, so I have the following chunk of code:

```
dt[, paste0('surv_rate_', 1:10^3) := Reduce('*', (1-dt[, paste0('col', 1:10^3)])^30, accumulate = T)]
```

I was not able to find any benchmarking on row-wise cumulative products like is shown above.

Can you think of any better/cleaner/faster methods for doing this in a data.table way?

(I thought of `as.data.table(t(cumprod(t(dt)))` as well but this appears to be taking forever with a table this size)

Comment: Certainly, `cumprod` (in some form) will be faster than `Reduce(\`*\`, ..)`. I think your `as.data.table(t(cumprod(t(dt))))` is not giving you the dimensions (nor the results) you're looking for, either. `t(apply(dt, 1, function(z) cumprod((1-z)^30)))` seems to be the most reasonable start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentionned in comments, another possible solution is to use `apply` along rows:

```
res1 <- 
 copy(dt)[, paste0('surv_rate_', 1:10^3) := transpose(apply((1-.SD)^30,1,cumprod,simplify=F))] 

res2 <- copy(dt)[, paste0('surv_rate_', 1:10^3) := Reduce('*', (1-dt[, paste0('col', 1:10^3)])^30, accumulate = T)]

all.equal(res1,res2)
[1] TRUE
```

However, your solution remains 30% faster:

```
Unit: milliseconds
                                                                                                                   expr       min
          copy(dt)[, `:=`(paste0("surv_rate_", 1:10^3), transpose(apply((1-.SD)^30, 1, cumprod, simplify = F)))] 1011.7095
 copy(dt)[, `:=`(paste0("surv_rate_", 1:10^3), Reduce("*", (1-dt[, paste0("col", 1:10^3)])^30, accumulate = T))]  793.5415
       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
 1246.993 1743.854 1546.797 2119.166 2772.646    10
 1046.194 1314.569 1249.636 1405.414 2496.858    10
```